# Index or range of second ocurence of bytes in file

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to find the second occurence of a byte pattern in a file. I can sucessfully find the first with:

`let mtrkChunk = Data(bytes: [0x4D, 0x54, 0x72, 0x6B] as [UInt8], count: 4)`
and then
`let mtrkChRng = data.range(of: mtrkChunk)`

But can't work out how to make it match the second occurence instead. Any help as ever would be appreciated

Comment: Are you looking for the second or for the last occurrence? There is a mismatch between your question title and question body.

Comment: My bad. Changed it now as should be second.

Comment: it looks like the range function takes an index parameter. So you should be able to take the mtrkChRng, advance it one and use that.  `data.range(of: mrtrkChunk, in: mtrkChRng)` kind of thing

Comment: @estabroo Thanks. Will check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the second occurrence this way :

```
if let rg1 = data.range(of: mtrkChunk),
    let rg2 = data[rg1.upperBound...].range(of: mtrkChunk) {
    print(rg2)   
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought about something like that but was just wondering if swift had something slicker available. Now I know :-)

Comment: @ChrisBarrett There's a ton of operations on `String` that you would want to be modified in a way so that they only apply to only part of a string. Building that into each of those operations would massively bloat the API (imagine adding `drop(while, skipping:)`, `shuffle(from:,to:)` counterparts of `drop(while:)`, `shuffle()`, etc.). Instead, the responsibility of slicing strings has been extracted into string slices, (err, `Substring`), on which you can do these ops. This keeps the whole API way leaner & more predictable (no1 will ever forget to add `from`/`to` args, bc they're never needed)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [options](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/searchoptions)

```
let mtrkChRng = data.range(of: mtrkChunk, options: .backwards)
```