# How to find the second range in the given string in swift

Tags: swift, string

I have a string say `"Hi,hello hi hello"` . How can I find the range of second `"hello"`.

```
let str = "Hi,hello hi hello"
let fullText = str.range(of: "hello", options: .caseInsensitive)
```

returns range of first occurred substring.

Comment: In this case you could add the `.backwards` option.

Comment: Hey thanks!. But what if it has three "hello" and i have to find the second range?@vadian

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55736255/1187415 – it works with strings as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a for-loop through the `String` and match the substrings with `"hello"` and get an array of `ClosedRange <Int>`.

```
let str = "Hi,hello hi hello"
let arr = Array(str)
var ranges = [ClosedRange<Int>]()

for index in stride(from: 0, to: str.count-1, by: 1) {
    if index+4 < str.count {
        if String(arr[index...index+4]) == "hello" {
            ranges.append(index...index+4)
        }
    }
}
```

Now use `ranges` `Array` to get whatever range you want using the index, i.e.

```
print(ranges[1])
```

Comment: Basically the "4" is length of the string to be searched + 1? Thanks!

Comment: @Shreeja Is string.count - 1 basically.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively a more generic solution.

You can pass the ordinal number (1-based) of the occurrence.
The code slices the string. The benefit is no extra copy of the string is created.

The function returns the range or `nil` if no match can be found.

```
extension String {
    func rangeOf(_ substring : String, ordinal : Int) -> Range<String.Index>? {
        var occurrence = 0
        var start = self.startIndex
        while start < endIndex {
            guard let range = self[start..<endIndex].range(of: substring, options: .caseInsensitive) else { return nil }
            occurrence += 1
            if occurrence == ordinal { return range }
            start = range.upperBound
        }
        return nil
    }
}

let string = "Hi,hello hi hello"
string.rangeOf("hello", ordinal: 2)
```

Forcing `String.Index` to *better-human-understandable* `Int` is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5 - Easy to read solution

Try this, will not consumes more than **O(n)** in terms of time:

```
func getFirstIndexOfSecondOccurrance(for string: String, wordToSearchFor: String) -> Int?
{
    guard let range = string.range(of: wordToSearchFor) else { return nil }
    let stringWithOutFirstWord = string.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: "")
    
    guard let secondRange = stringWithOutFirstWord.range(of: wordToSearchFor) else { return nil }
    let nsRange = NSRange(secondRange, in: stringWithOutFirstWord)
    
    return nsRange.lowerBound + wordToSearchFor.count
}
```

Then you can call it as follows:

```
let wordToSearchFor = "Click"
let string = "Please Click Here Click Here Click"
if let index = getFirstIndexOfSecondOccurrance(for: string, wordToSearchFor: wordToSearchFor)
{
   print(index)
}
```